# How to use transformers pipeline with multi-gpu?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

```
ner_model = pipeline('ner', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, device=0, grouped_entities=True)
```

the ***device*** indicated pipeline to use no_gpu=0(only using GPU), please show me how to use multi-gpu.

Comment: There is a `Pipeline._config.device` option. I think this is a good point to start investigation. Also there is an issue about global configuration for Pipeline settings in trankit repo. Create two pipelines for two GPUs and assign different tasks to them.

Answer (score 4):

There is an argument called `device_map` for the pipelines in the `transformers` lib; see [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.27.1/en/main_classes/pipelines). It comes from the `accelerate` module; see [here](https://huggingface.co/docs/accelerate/usage_guides/big_modeling). You can specify a custom model dispatch, but you can also have it inferred automatically with `device_map=" auto"`. Eventually, you might need additional configuration for the tokenizer, but it should look like this:

```py
ner_model = pipeline('ner', model=model, tokenizer=tokenizer, device_map="auto", grouped_entities=True)
```

Comment: device_map="auto" worked for me while loading a model on multiple gpus. However when I do the inference, the input is unable to fit on the gpu 0. I can see my gpu 3 have space left. how do i specify the target gpu to store the input while doing the inference?